# How to store the returning value of an NSArray.objectAtIndex to an NSString variable

Tags: objective-c, class, nsstring, nsarray

I'm new to programming using objective c, I've only used java in the past. I'm trying to code a quick hangman game and I've come across errors that for the life of me I can't find a solution to.

So in this method, I'm trying to pick a random word from an NSArray and setting it equal to the instance variable word.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Hangman : NSObject
{
    NSString *word;
}
-(void) randomWord;
-(void) guessLettter: (char) g;
-(void) guessWord: (NSString*) guess;
-(void) displayLetters: (char) x;
@end

#import "Hangman.h"
@implementation Hangman

-(void) randomWord;
{

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mercedes", @"Banana", @"Porsche",
                  @"Dinosaur", @"Blue", @"owls", @"chicken", @"Lollipop", @"Table",
                  @"Hello", @"Corn", @"Uniform",nil];
int num = 11;
NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(11);
word = *[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)r];


}
```

But trying to set word equal to whatever object is returned is giving me an error about assigning NSString Strong to type 'id' and I don't know what 'id' is.

Comment: change `-(void) randomWord;` to `(NSString *)randomWord` then before the last `}` add `return word;`

Comment: @Tj3n I did as you said but the error is still there about there being an incompatible type id

Comment: maybe its in your `word = *[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)r];`, it should be `word = [array objectAtIndex:r];`

Comment: @Tj3n yay it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo. This line:

```
word = *[array objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)r];
```

should be:

```
word = [array objectAtIndex:r];
```

or even better:

```
word = array[r];
```

Side note: Don't put the ivar in the .h file. Put it in the .m file. The public doesn't need to know about private details.

.h:

```
@interface Hangman : NSObject

-(void) randomWord;
-(void) guessLettter: (char) g;
-(void) guessWord: (NSString*) guess;
-(void) displayLetters: (char) x;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "Hangman.h"

@implementation Hangman {
    NSString *word;
}

-(void)randomWord
{
    NSArray *array = @[@"Mercedes", @"Banana", @"Porsche",
                  @"Dinosaur", @"Blue", @"owls", @"chicken", @"Lollipop", @"Table",
                  @"Hello", @"Corn", @"Uniform"];
    NSUInteger r = arc4random_uniform(11);
    word = array[r];
}
```

Also get rid of the semicolon after the name of the `randomWord` method in the .m file.

And notice the use of modern array syntax.